# is there anyway to update a web user control code (ascx.cs) file without compile the entire site?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, user-controls, webforms

Thanks first.
I'm using vs2010, asp.net 4 webform.

Is there anyway which I can update a code behind file (ascx.cs) file without compile the whole site?
Because I just want to debug some ascx.cs file, and compile a big whole site will cost 1 minutes at least.

Answer (score 1):

Put breakpoint in the user control.
When breakpoint hits, you can modify code and run it when completed.
**Note:** Your VS setting must enable to allow changes on debugging and You can't modified in a depth otherwise it will ask for restart app.